# Windows Phone 10 Univrsal - get online contacts

Tags: contacts, windows-10-universal

I can get all the contacts from a windows phone 10 device.
I want to know if a contact is local contact or an online contact.
I used this code to indicate:

```
ContactStore contactstore = await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync(ContactStoreAccessType.AllContactsReadOnly);
ContactList = await contactstore.FindContactsAsync();
         if (ContactList.Count > 0)
                        {
                        ienum = ContactList.GetEnumerator();
                        ienum.MoveNext();
                        IEnumerator<ContactConnectedServiceAccount> enum2 = ienum.Current.ConnectedServiceAccounts.GetEnumerator();
                        enum2.MoveNext();
                        string id = enum2.Current.ServiceName;
```

but it get to the catch exception scope..

I also tried to change the access type from AllContactsReadOnly to AppContactsReadWrite and it doesn't work and does the same.

Comment: What you mean by local and online contact, `RequestStoreAsync` method retrieves a ContactStore object that enables searching or retrieving contacts on the device.

Comment: Right. I'm looking for contacts that would not got imported from G-Mail or something familiar to this. only the contacts that created locally.